# Load all the images under a specified folder from gallery into PWA Application using Angular 6

Tags: android, ios, angular, angular6, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a PWA application where I need to display all the images under a given path (eg. all the images stored under "Downloads" folder in mobile device) in a customized grid view.

Is there any option to fetch all the image source and display the same in angular PWA application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to cache all images under a folder? if so, you can do it by having a wildcard cache on a folder like below which is added for "assets" folder.

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Yes, Im trying to store images and videos downloaded from the server. I am new to PWA. Could you pls explain the flow in detail?

Comment: In the above code block which is from ngsw-config.json file (generated by angular PWA CLI) - "/assets/**" denotes all the files under that path will be cached. You can change that to some other folder name or add more of your folder names.

Comment: You have to spend some time reading it to know if you are new to this. SO can only get you answer if you have specific question or issue. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro